# quartz scheduler2.2.x creating sqlserver database schema?

Tags: java, sql-server, database, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am new to Quartz. I have done some sample with RAM jobstore . After that I am trying to do smaples for JDBC jobstore . I am having SQL server as my database.

In my quartz.properties,

```
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck: true  

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName =OZS_SCHEDULAR  
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool  
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 4  
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true  
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5  


#specify the jobstore used  
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000  
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX  
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate  
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false  


#The datasource for the jobstore that is to be used  
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS  

#quartz table prefixes in the database  
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = WB_QRTZ_  
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000  
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false  

#The details of the datasource specified previously  
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver =net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver  
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL =jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.160.100.24:1433;databaseName=Test  
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user =admin  
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = password
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 20  


org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false  
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000  

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
```

But I don't have the database structure for quartz. I have searched a lot in google to find the queries of SQL SERVER to create QUARTZ database schema .

But I found this link only.http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/migration-guide   .

Please help me to create a new database schema to quartz 2.2.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

For Quartz 2.3.0 or greater, none of the solutions above worked for me.

You need to go to the [releases section in their GitHub repo](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/releases), download the distributable file (a `tar.gz` file), extract it and find the appropriate `.sql` file for your RDBMS, within:

`quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/`

**(Bonus)** For example, if someone wants to generate the Quartz DB schema for a recent version of **MySQL**, they must be interested in using `tables_mysql_innodb.sql` instead of `tables_mysql.sql`.

**Edit:**
You might want to also prepend the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `quartz`
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

USE quartz;
```

Comment: what's the value for your jdbcUrl parameter then? `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz` because if I don't create the quartz db I get an error like `quartz` db doesn't exists.

Answer (score 5):

For every quartz version there is separate schema for each of the supported databases. U can select the quartz version [here](http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/quartz/tags/) and then navigate to distribution/src/main/assembly/root/docs/dbTables/ for the corresponding quartz version and u can get the schema for all supported databases.

Answer (score 3):

I have got the **sqlserver** database schema queries in the **docs/dbTables** directory of the Quartz distribution.

Here u can find all the database queries.

**Referal Link :** http://quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/#page/Quartz_Scheduler_Documentation_Set%2Fco-jstr_jdbcjobstore.html%23

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this: http://teknosrc.com/how-setup-quartz-scheduler-server-with-mysql-database/

you need to download quartz distribution, you'll find schema fo most data bases.